# Android KitKat (Api 19) ContentResolver do not writes messages (returns null)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-contentresolver

I'm writing replacement for default SMS app in KitKat. I've read lots of stuff
like: [Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

I have the following code:

```
public void saveMessage(Context context, String addr, String text){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, addr );
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.DATE, 0);
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.DATE_SENT, 0);
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.BODY, text);
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.READ, 0 );
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.STATUS, 0 );
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.TYPE, Telephony.Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX);
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.SEEN, 0;
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.THREAD_ID, 0);
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.CREATOR, "");
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.ERROR_CODE, 0);
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.LOCKED, 0);
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.PERSON, 0);
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.SUBJECT, "");

    Uri mMessageUri = Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI;
    Uri result = context.getContentResolver().insert(mMessageUri, values);

}
```

And manifest looks like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MessageListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ConversationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_conversation" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
    <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
        android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

AS you can see I'm able to select this app as default SMS app in system.
When I receive message and call **saveMessage** function it writes nothing.
Neither to content://sms, not to content://sms/inbox, nor to content://sms/sent.

What am I missing here? Do I need more permissions to define?

Comment: Thanks, but already tried this. I also tried to fill each value with non-zero. It still doesn't write

Comment: Yes, my receiver responses to SMS_DELIVER_ACTION. Which is possible only if it's selected as default. 
This all happens on real device, but that's an idea to test it on emulator. Probably something wrong with my particular firmware. It's android 4.4.2

Comment: Same behavior on emulator

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem!

insert fails when I try to write anything to CREATOR column because it's readonly.

I should have read more carefully [API docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html#CREATOR)